# Add text to waterfallchart in R

Tags: r, waterfall

Hello I would like to add text of data on each bar. Someone can help me? Thanks.

```
library(waterfall)
mydata=data.frame(Item=as.factor(c('Before','Factor A','Factor B','Factor C','Factor D','Factor E','Factor F','Factor G')),
data=c(325,-32,-105,38,86,97,232,389))
waterfallchart(Item~data,data=mydata)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `waterfall()` function in the `waterfalls` package, (Note. not `waterfall` package) has something similar already built in:

```
library(waterfalls)
mydata=data.frame(Item=as.factor(c('Before','Factor A','Factor B','Factor C','Factor D','Factor E','Factor F','Factor G')),
                  data=c(325,-32,-105,38,86,97,232,389))
waterfall(values=mydata$data, labels=as.character(mydata$Item), calc_total = T)
```

[image]